# Conflict between JT400 and UCanAccess?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, jt400, ucanaccess

Since I have added to reference libraries ucanaccess-2.0.3.jar (eclipse Luna), I receive this error while executing my program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
```

referenced to a row of code that contains JT400 connection, and that works if I don't include ucanaccess jar in my project, as follows:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://"+systemi,user,pass);
return c;
```

so I'm confused...
I also have a class that does ucanaccess connection, but it's not invocated until I press a button:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://M:/FServer.mdb"); 
return c;
```

Is it a conflict of libraries?
Has anyone sperimented it yet?

Comment: I've found this.. Is this a known issue? bad... http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/0b85dea2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue you linked is likely related to a mdb corrupted and it's totally unrelated to your NoClassDefFoundError problem. 
Also it's impossible a specific conflict problem with the AS400JDBCDriver, so it  would be better to focus on the  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. It means there is a lack in your runtime environment classpath.
You should firstly check if you are using java 6 or older,  if there are  all UCanAccess dependencies  in your classpath  (see the jars in the lib folder of the UCanAccess distribution: jackcess, hsqldb,commons-logging and commons-lang) and if they aren't in  conflict with the jars already in the classpath (e.g., presence of an old and  incompatible version of jackcess).
Cheers Marco

Comment: It was a conflict between jar files in the lib path, making different paths for external jars has resolved my problem. PS: same issue in java 7 and 8, with the relative package. Thanks Marco.